# Is it possible to call ./executable from a launch file?

Tags: arduino, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using [arduino-serial](https://github.com/todbot/arduino-serial) to send a string to arduino through serial port. I'm able to do this on the console:

./arduino-serial -b 9600 -p /dev/tty.usbserial -s 6

Is it possible to call this on a launch file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222069/is-it-possible-to-call-./executable-from-a-launch-file?/) by [sergiosrl](https://answers.ros.org/users/25267/sergiosrl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-12-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Adding to @Mehdi.'s answer, you can specify arguments.

```
<node pkg="my_package" type="arduino-serial" name="foo" args="-b 9600 -p /dev/tty.usbserial -s 6" />
```

Anyways these require that your executable files are located in a ROS package in order to utilize `node` tag.

Also see:
http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node and http://answers.ros.org/question/54640/roslaunch-external-program/

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could create a python (.py) or a bash (.sh) script that runs this command and start it as if it was a node in roslaunch.

```
<node name="foo" pkg="my_package" type="my_script" />
```

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2015-12-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1